# What's the difference between "cъездить" and "поездить"?

Tags: значения, глаголы, разница, глаголы-движения, слова

What's the difference between the two perfectives "cъездить" and "поездить"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Съездить» means one is going to get to a certain place by air, road, sea/river or rail, then come back.

a) intent or need or want

I need to get to my dacha. Мне надо **съездить** на дачу.

I'm going to go to London.  Я собираюсь **съездить** в Лондон.

I am going to drive to the pharmacy. Я собираюсь **съездить** в аптеку.

I want to go to Lake Baikal. Я хочу **съездить** на озеро Байкал.

Regardless of whether one is going to go to a certain place by plane or boat, **съездить** is usually used.

b)past tense

Я **съездил** в Лондон/на дачу/в аптеку/озеро Байкал. This means I went to London/to a pharmacy/to the dacha/to Lake Baikal and came back.

«Поездить» means one is going to take their time and visit places, or take a road trip.

There's no certainty as to where exactly they're going or how long it's going to take.

a)intent or need or want

I'm going/want to travel the world/America. Я собираюсь/хочу **поездить** по миру/ по Америке.

I'm going/need/want to do some shopping. Я собираюсь/хочу/мне надо **поездить** по магазинам.

b)past tense

I traveled the world/America/did some shopping. Я **поездил** по миру/по Америке/по магазинам.

Answer (score 5):

1. "Съездить" means "to go to a certain place and return". "Я съездил в Москву".
2. "Поездить" means "to spend some time driving, traveling; to make several trips". "Я поездил по Москве".

Comment: Thank you very much! This is so helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. "Съездить по уху" means to hit someone on the side of the head.
2. "Поездить по ушам" means to give someone a lot of BS.